# Relate certain fields in filemaker pro table to another table

Tags: filemaker

I have a filemaker pro table with 150 fields storing one value in each field.  is there a way to relate another table that stores meta info for most of these field?

Table 1

Record 1

| FieldName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Date | 20200930 |
| RRSD | 2536789 |
| HB16278 | 23456 |
| HB17829 | 2387 |
| HR0198 | 982876 |

Record 2

| FieldName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Date | 20200930 |
| RRSD | 273896 |
| HB16278 | 29837 |
| HB17829 | 789276 |
| HR0198 | 102876 |

Table 2

Record 1

| FieldName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ID | HB16278 |
| Name | Cash and Cash Eq |
| Sect | RRCON |
| Mult | -1 |

Record 2

| FieldName | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ID | HB17829 |
| Name | Deposits - Call |
| Sect | RRCON |
| Mult | 1 |

I am trying to relate Table 2 to Table 1 keyed to certain fields in table 1...  HB16278, HB17829, HR0198.  The difference in what I have done in the past is I am trying to relate records in another table to a field or field name rather than a value in that field.

Comment: You cannot define a relationship matching a field name in one table to a field value in another table. If (!) I understand your question correctly, you would need to add 150 fields to your Table 1, then define 150 relationships to 150 occurrences of Table 2. This doesn't sound like a viable solution. I would suggest you restructure your data - but I cannot say how based on such an abstract description.

Comment: thanks.  thats basically what I wanted to know... that there is no way to match a field value in Table 2 to a field name in Table 1.  would have been nice in this instance.  I can combine the tables and carry 5x  duplicated data... was trying to avoid.

Comment: *"carry 5x duplicated data"*  That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Just point out, the field name is the same for every single record in the table, so relating to that table is pointless, just use the "X" in the relationship to relate to every record in that table. If on the otherhand you want to relate from "HB16278" to another table with HB16278 as a value then one way is to use a global field on the from side, and set the value of the global to HB16278, and that will match all records on the other side with value HB16278. You can change the global value at any time to relate to whatever records you want, e.g. from HB16278 to HR0198

Comment: yes on the "otherhand" assumption.  I would like to access fields/values for record HB16278 in table 2 in association with field HB16278 in table 1.  I will look at global fields as a way to do this.  Thanks for your direction.